# PySpark DataFrame unable to drop duplicates

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hello I have created a spark dataframe, and I am trying to remove duplicates:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='id')
```

I get the following error:

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonUtils.toSeq. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method toSeq([class java.lang.String]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:335)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:360)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:254)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Am using
osx 10.11.4, spark 1.6.1

I ran a jupyter notebook like this

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook' pyspark
```

Is there some other configurations that I might have missed out or got wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Argument for `drop_duplicates` / `dropDuplicates` should be a collection of names, which Java equivalent can be converted to Scala `Seq`, not a single string. You can use either a `list`:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id'])
```

or a `tuple`:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=('id', ))
```

Comment: Damn, thanks. I didn't see that properly. Thought it worked similar to pandas dfs.